# Onto property of the function

Tags: calculus, functions, nonlinear-analysis

How can we prove the onto property of this non-homogeneous function
$$f(x)= (|x|^{p-2} + |x|^{q-2}) x \quad \text{for} \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \text{where} \quad p, q >1.$$

Any ideas (without performing any complicative calculations)?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$, IVT implies $\mathbb{R}^+ \subset \mathrm{Im}(f)$.

Can you do the other side?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, IVT implies the onto property. Btw $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $ x \to -\infty.$

Comment: @R.Arora indeed. So $f(0)=0$ bounds the RHS and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ on the LHS and IVT applies again